# VAT not being removed when adding a number to businessTaxID

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Folks, just wondering if anyone has further knowledge on Craft Commerce's Tax Rates? I am setting up my first commerce store and the client requires that if the customer is buying from the EU, and has a valid VAT number, they then *do not* pay the 20% VAT.

I have my Tax Categories, Zones and Rates set up, and have checked the option to 'Don't apply this tax when the shipping address has a valid VAT ID' - however when it comes to the payment screen after putting in a VAT number in the businessTaxId input on the Shipping Address screen, it does not deduct the 20% added VAT. It does pick up the correct Tax Zone as I can see it is EU Tax that has been added, it is just not deducting when I enter a VAT ID.

Just wondering is there something else that I would need to be covering first before this works? Apologies if this is a little too vague.

I am currently running the latest version of Craft & Craft Commerce, and working from the base files that you get when you download.

***Edit
I have just noticed this error in the commerce.log file if it helps matters***

```
[Forced] Communication with VAT API failed: MS_UNAVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commerce, by default, uses [this library](https://github.com/snowcap/vat-validation) for VAT validation.

That library is just a wrapper for a European SOAP endpoint for these types of things at http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

The error code `MS_UNAVAILABLE` that endpoint can return says:

> The Member State service is unavailable, try again later or with another Member State;

So I'm guessing an invalid member state was selected, or they are having some technical difficulties on their end.

Comment: Thanks Brad, it seemed to be an error on their end.  When I put the same VAT number into this webpage http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html it returned an error and asked to try again later.